# jquery how to stack/toggle divs visibility?

Tags: jquery

I have two divs. I wish to display one after another. So, the first fade in, then fade out, then de second fade in, then fade out.

```
$('[class^="flash"]').each(function(index) {
  $(this).fadeToggle();
});

<div class="flash-error">You have an error.</div>
<div class="flash-info">You may do this to avoid that error.</div>
```

The effect is made at the same time, while it should be one after another.

Can I have a push here?

Comment: When do you want to switch/toggle divs? onclick? Do you have any time to toggle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5AYQk/

Comment: @Unknown When the user gets redirected to the page, it should see this messages. So, page load or document ready should be fine. Yes messages should have a delay to allow users to read the messages.

Comment: You want an infinite loop or just to end having a fade out?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan End, after the last iterated element fades out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rotig/1/edit)**

```
$('[class^="flash"]').hide().each(function(index, elemenet){   
   $(elemenet).delay(i*2000).fadeTo(500,1, function(){
     $(this).delay(1000).fadeTo(500,0);
   });
});
```

The timing logic: 1000 + 500 + 500 = 2000
You can add as much `flash` elements as you need in your HTML (see demo).

They show one after another cause for every targeted `'[class^="flash"]'` element, we pass among the `each()` arguments the `i` (index) value of the current element in stack (0, 1, if you have two elements). Than the math is simple: `$(element).delay(i*2000)` means the first will have assigned a delay of 0 (0*2000=0) and the second element will have a 2000 delay before appearing cause of 1*2000 (1*2000=2000)

Comment: I will read about each argument on the documentation. That seems to be cleanest solution, while I still need to study in order to understand why does it show one after another.

Comment: One last question: what's the role of position absolute? Can it be position agostic? It seems that position absolute will allow to mimify  the display:none;

Comment: @MEM ohh nice you noticed it, as not knowing your original CSS I supposed you had that line already! I used it in order to stack all my elements one-over-each-other! You can notice the difference if you remove the jQuery code and toggle that CSS line (see what happens: if you remove position:absolute; the elements will be one-under the other. we don't want that right?)

Comment: Actually, it was position relative as by default. But I can well change to position absolute, and set a z-index, to make sure this messages will appear always on top. This may have an advantage, because, with position absolute, it will ignore the other elements position. However, on same cases, we may wish the message to slide down (and push down other page elements already present). On those cases, position relative would be preferable. I presume, however, this can't be done because, fadeTo will change the opacity of a given element, but that element will always have display block; - Correct?

Comment: @MEM z-index is not needed at all... Yes, in that case once a fadeOut finishes you may want to `.hide()` that element

Comment: @MEM here's an example without absolute but with .hide() : http://jsbin.com/rotig/3/edit

Comment: :) About z-index: When I add it, the flash message appears on top of this bootstrap navigator. Without it, it never shows.

Comment: @MEM ahh, than it's about a load of other elements :) you're free to do whatever it's needed, just make it work! :D

Comment: Thanks for all, and also for the explanation. I will carefully study it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout and multiply it by the index value. Change `1000` to be however long you wish the delay. Note that the first `index` value will be `0` so `0 * anything` will always be `0`. Do `index+1 * anything` if you wish to change this default behavior.

```
$('[class^="flash"]').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         $this.fadeToggle();
    }, index * 1000);
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29mFx/)

**EDIT**

If you wish to have the second only appear after the first, it should start invisible to begin with, given that you're using fade toggle:

```
.flash-info{
    display:none;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dme2d/)

Comment: I end up finding that index solution and tried before, but, even on your example, you see that the second message appears as well, while the second message should only appear, after the first one disappears. (sorry for being picky). I have a vague idea about a callback, but not sure where to put it...

Comment: @MEM Please see the EDIT in my post.

Comment: Tried that as well, but I was unable to change the delay time of the first message. I need it to stay longer on the screen. It happened to me, just as it happen on your fiddle. Any clue on how to give more time to the first message?

Comment: @MEM as I explained in my post, the first `index` value is always `0`. `0 * anything` will be 0. Change it so that `var index = index+3` for instance. [Here's another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGwuL/)

Comment: I understand. One last comment. In order to display one after another, you've chosen to do that using CSS. However, not always the info will appear after another element, hence, it should not always be hidden. I guess you have choose css to display none, so that there's not a undesired blink when the page loads, correct? Do you happen to know any other way to rely on jquery to display none that element, without recurring to css and still avoid the blink? Or, would it be better, if I found a more specific selector for this case, and still use css?

Comment: @MEM If it's necessary, you could always just use an inline CSS style, such as `style="display:none;"` on that element. However, given that fact, there will always be the chance the element will be visible while the page loads as your code executes within `$(document).ready()`. That being said, I would always choose CSS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Yes, we need to add a higher number on the index to make it last longer (as Ohgodwhy told on comments). But, the last message should fade out at the end. I end up with this, but perhaps this could be simplified? Please advice: http://jsfiddle.net/MGwuL/1/

Comment: @MEM for an advice you can check my answer. I don't find any need to set timeouts inside an each loop.

Comment: Thanks. I will need to abstract the all thing, and try to change effects and so on, play with position relative and absolute etc... please, don't delete your answer. And, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jjH9W/3/

```
$('[class^="flash"]').hide()
$('[class^="flash"]').eq(0).fadeIn(2000,function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
});
setTimeout(function(){
    $('[class^="flash"]').eq(1).fadeIn(2000,function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    });
},4000);
```

Comment: Yes. Like that. Exactly. But, the only selector I may have is: '[class^="flash"]'. And that's the hard part, I guess. Because, how can we abstract know, when should we fadein or fadeout, the toogle solves it, but, if we use it, we need perhaps a callback... but where to call it?

Comment: Care to explain why the `eq(1)` and `eq(0)` are those indexes? What if instead of 2 we have 10? And, what does the * there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reason that he has to use `*[class^="flash"]`. The only time this would be true is if we were filtering against these elements.

Comment: `$('[class^="flash"]').hide();`

Comment: `eq(0)` and `eq(1)` are the order that the selected elements are written in the html code! 0 is the first one, 1 is the second one and * means all elements used in the html, you have to select something in order to check its class!\

Comment: haven't tested it without the `*`, let me check and respond again!

Comment: you guys were right, no need to use `*`, sorry it was my bad

Comment: @AminJafari you should also know that there's **no need to use `each` to hide a collection of elements**. Have you seen my comment? `$('[class^="flash"]').hide();`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks again, taught me a lot today! ;-)